# Azure Keyvault: Getting forbidden error if user is having direct access via Group to Key Vault

Tags: azure-keyvault

When we are trying to retrieve secret from keyvault using `KeyVaultClient` (c#) we are getting `403 access denied` even though the same user can access the vault secret from *Azure Portal*. If we give explicit access to the user on key vault then we are able to retrieve the secrets. This looks like an issue and please help on possible workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have a service principal created for your application yet. If so, create that first and then use the object ID of the service principal to authorize access for the application. If you are using a VM you also need to add the VM service principal to the Keyvault's policies.

Take a look at this [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/AutoRest/src/KeyVault/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Samples/scripts/GetAppConfigSettings.ps1#L53-L62) to see how to create application and service principal and [give permission to the service principal](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/AutoRest/src/KeyVault/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Samples/scripts/GetAppConfigSettings.ps1#L96-L100).

Comment: We are connecting with user credential not  with service application and if user has access to key vault by direct permission (not by group )  we are able to retrieve secrets.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to while generating token Group claims were not getting set and hence key vault was checking only of  direct permissions.  Once we enable group claims  by following these steps  from [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/)  then it is working fine now ..